# Refactor this Java code checking if a String contains any of these possibilities?

Tags: java, string, refactoring, loops

I am needing to check if a string does NOT contain **any** of these string possibilities:

MNC
BRA
LEB
MAR
RVC
WAY
GLZ
WWW
HYB

My current code :

```
 if(selectedLocation.equals("OTH"))
 {
    if(!currentClassLocation.equals("MNC") &&
                        !currentClassLocation.equals("BRA") &&
                        !currentClassLocation.equals("LEB") &&
                        !currentClassLocation.equals("MAR") &&
                        !currentClassLocation.equals("RVC") &&
                        !currentClassLocation.equals("WAY") &&
                        !currentClassLocation.equals("GLZ") &&
                        !currentClassLocation.equals("WWW") &&
                        !currentClassLocation.equals("HYB"))
                    {
                         //Awesome, I need this string! I operate on it here.
                    }
 }
```

Long story short, I can't use a for-loop. Is there a way I can check if the string doesn't contain any of these without iteration?

Comment: Maybre regular expressions?

Comment: Can you put them in a Set and use `!Set.contains(currentClassLocation)`?

Comment: Why not use a For-loop (or an other loop)?

Comment: If you dont want loops then what is wrong with current implementation? It looks all good.

Comment: You might want contains() instead of equals(), or you won't have many matches.

Comment: @smit Just because I thought it smelled bad and there was a better way to do it, not because it doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a `HashSet`:

```
Set<String> invalidSequences = new HashSet<String>();
invalidSequences.add("MNC");
invalidSequences.add("BRA");
invalidSequences.add("LEB");
// Remaining sequences ...

if (!invalidSequences.contains(currentClassLocation)) {
    // Awesome, I need this string...
}
```

Comment: Code to the interface; i.e. `Set<String> invalidSequences = new HashSet<String>();`

Answer (score 2):

Try adding those strings to Set then look up using contains which will be O(c):

```
public class Filter {
   Set<String> exclusionSet = new HashSet<String>();

   public Filter( String... excludes ) {
       for( String exclusion : excludes ) {
          exclusionSet.add( exclusion );
       }
   }

   public boolean exclude( String src ) {
     return exclusionSet.contains( src );
  }


   public static void main( String[] args ) {
       Filter filter = new Filter( "MNC BRA LEB MAR RVC WAY GLZ WWW HYB".split(" ") );

       for( String arg : args ) {
           System.out.println( arg + " is excluded? " + filter.exclude( arg ) );
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the clean setup - but `filter.exclude(x)` sounds like add x to the list of filtered value. I would have named it `filter.isExcluded(x)` or `filter.matches(x)` maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Make a HashSet of your strings, and do a O(1) check to see if the current class location exists in your set of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try a variation  (using your strings) of this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*(AIN|BIN|CIN|Blam).*)*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string_to_test);
```

Test java regex patterns here: [Java Regex Tester](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/RegexTester/regex-tester.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a for-loop you could simply use a variable

```
String[] data = {"BRA","LEB","MAR","RVC","WAY","GLZ","WWW","HYB"};

if(selectedLocation.equals("OTH"))
{
   boolean chk = false;
   for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
      chk |= currentClassLocation.equals(data[i]);

   if(!chk){
      //Awesome, I need this string! I operate on it here.
   }

}
```

Comment: Yes, it's the same as var = var || boolen, similar to += or -=

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this if you don't want to manually add the data to set.

```
import java.util.Arrays;


public class StringFind {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String stringtotest = "MNC";
        String dataString = "MNC BRA LEB MAR RVC WAY GLZ WWW HYB";
        String[] dataArray= dataString.split(" ");
        Arrays.sort(dataArray); // You can omit this if data is already sorted.
        if(Arrays.binarySearch(dataArray, stringtotest)<0){
            System.out.println("Does not Exists");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Exists");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a config file so that the list of invalid sequences becomes configurable. For this is the smelliest bit, the series of magic letter combinations. Moving it to a set does not help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Using a string array:

```
String[] arr = {"MNC", "BRA", "LEB", "MAR", "RVC", "WAY", "GLZ", "WWW", "HYB"};
List list = Arrays.asList(arr);
if (!list.contains(currentClassLocation)) {
   ...
}
```